# Regex to match ZIP code without punctuation

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file with a bunch of different ZIP codes:

```
12345
12345-6789
1234567890
12345:6789
12345-7890
12:1234678
```

I want to only match on codes that have the format `12345` or `12345-6789`, but ignore all other forms.

I have my regex as:

`grep -E '\<[0-9]{5}\>[^[:punct:]]|\<[0-9]{5}\>-[0-9]{4}' samplefile`

It matches on the `12345-6789` because the "or" clause matches on that particular one. I am confused as to why it won't match on the first `12345` since my expression should say "match on 5 numbers but ignore any punctuation."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An expression that matches your desired output is:

```
egrep "^[0-9]{5}([-][0-9]{4})?$" samplefile
```

The expression breakdown:

`^[0-9]{5}` - Find a line that starts with 5 digits. `^` means start of line and `[0-9]{5}` means exactly five digits between zero and nine.

`([-][0-9]{4})?$` - May end with a dash and four digits or nothing at all. `()` groups the expressions together, `[-]` represents the dash character, `[0-9]{4}` represents exactly four digits between zero and nine, `?` indicates the grouped expression either exists entirely or does not exist and `$` marks the end of the line.

**test.dat**

```
12345
12345-6789
1234567890
12345:6789
12345-7890
12:1234678
```

Running the expression on the test data:

```
mike@test:~$ egrep "^[0-9]{5}([-][0-9]{4})?$" test.dat 
12345
12345-6789
12345-7890
```

Additional info: `grep -E` can alternatively be written as `egrep`. This also works for `grep -F` which is the same as `fgrep` and `grep -r` which is the same as `rgrep`.

Comment: Makes sense. I was trying to do it the opposite way instead of going from the beginning. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It won't match "12345" but will match "12345a". The first clause needs to end in a non-punctuation character, the way you wrote it.

Consider Mike's answer; it's clearer.